Time Modified of old file has changed
Properties of file in 2 drives
On PC Windows 10, Version 22H2
For a while now I have used a program to backup files that have changed. It checks the timestamp using File.GetLastWriteTime and copies using File.Copy.
Today, instead of copying just the changed files as usual, it started copying hundreds of files. I stopped it to investigate and found that the remaining files in the target have a Date/Time Modified stamp 1 hour earlier and 0, 1, or 2 seconds later than the target. So the program is picking them up as "Newer". The files that had been copied have the same hour but are still a few seconds later than the source.
The picture shows the Properties of a typical file which had not yet been updated:
source Modified = 07 March 2019, 23:11:25
target Modified = 07 March 2019, 22:11:26
I have not changed this file for years.
Source drive is SSD NTFS. Target drive is SSD FAT32. The target drive was added in late February and the files were first backed up to it soon after.
I am in the UK and the clocks have just gone forward an hour. My PC shows the correct current local time (BST). I cannot imagine how these timestamps can differ. Will it happen again next year
I have looked at Modified date/time stamp for many files.
I changed over to Robocopy to backup but, of course, this too started to copy hundreds of files.
For files which have not changed for years, I expect the Modified date/time to be the same in the source & target: at least within a few seconds.
